# problem with R.drawable class and SVN

Tags: android, svn, subclipse

I have a project which is connected to SVN server. I use Subclipse as the SVN Client.

I have some problem which I don't know what's the cause. the problem is,when i delete some images from res/drawable folder my program's images become so broken. lets say for example

- the splash screen image changed with some button image
- the button image changed with background image
- etc,, everything is changed.

The problem will be gone if I revert back the change (restore the deleted images). That will be some trouble if I can't delete any unused resources at all. I don't have any idea about this problem. does anybody ever have the same problem?

note : I deleted the images when my connection is off. is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should commit deleting changes
2. Try to rebuild R class.